# Adding error message when a specific drop down option is selected

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu, contacts

Ok guys, Ive done some researching and can't find something that works to solve my problem even though I'm sure its a simple fix :)

I have a simple contact form in which the first line is a drop down selection. This drop down determines which employee the form is submitted to. I just want to make my default option of "Please Select Category" return an error message so that the submitter must go back and select one of the options to get the form sent. When nothing is selected, its creating a lot of junk mail to the default email.

Here is the drop down bit of code:

```
                <tr>
            <td><label for="sendTo">Category (required):</label></td>
            <td>
                <select id="sendTo" name="sendTo">
                    <option id="pleaseSelectcategory1" value="pleaseSelectcategory1">Please Select Category</option>
                    <option id="aftermarketCustomerservice" value="aftermarketCustomerservice">Aftermarket Customer Service</option>
                    <option id="technicalAssistance" value="technicalAssistance">Technical Assistance</option>
                    <option id="aftermarketSales" value="aftermarketSales">Aftermarket Sales</option>
                    <option id="performanceProducts" value="performanceProducts">Performance Products & Sales</option>
                    <option id="oemSales" value="oemSales">OEM Sales</option>
                    <option id="exportSales" value="exportSales">Export Sales</option>
                    <option id="generalFeedback" value="generalFeedback">General Feedback</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
```

I just need what to put in my html, if anything, to make this error message occur and in my php file. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `if($_POST['sendTo'] == "pleaseSelectcategory1"){ // }`

Comment: Using Javascript to handle this would avoid useless server exchanges. Just google "form validation with javascript". (It doesn't mean that double checking it server side later on isn't good btw)

Comment: @Fred-ii- That appears to stop the email, but how would i alert people to select that category to get it sent correctly?

Comment: @ClémentMalet 

    <script>
function validateForm() {

   if( document.contactForm.sendTo.value == "pleaseSelectcategory1" )
   {
     alert( "Please Select a Category" );
     document.contacctForm.sendTo.focus() ;
     return false;
   }

}
</script>

- added this bit and nothing happens

Comment: @KJones `if($_POST['sendTo'] == "pleaseSelectcategory1"){ echo "Choose a category"; exit; }` you can add a link in there too if you want. But a mix of JS would be a nice touch. You could look into Ajax also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- when i add `if ($_POST['sendTo'] == "pleaseSelectcategory1"){ // }` it stops the email with no error message. When I add `if($_POST['sendTo'] == "pleaseSelectcategory1"){ echo "Choose a category"; exit; }` it shows the error message but continues to send the email anyway, thoughts?

Comment: Show your full code.

Comment: You may need to add `if(isset($_POST['sendTo']) && !empty($_POST['sendTo']))` - Do ask the other guys who gave you answers below, see what they can do. I can't keep guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Javascript function to validate your form prior to posting the data. This is better for UX, and will prevent the form from even reaching the PHP post function.

In your form have the `onsubmit` field call a Javascript function:

```
<form name="form" id="form" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST">
```

and your Javascript function for checking the select box value:

```
// Basic form validation for select box.
function validateForm() {
    if (document.getElementById("sendTo").value != null && docmument.getElementById("sendTo").value != "pleaseSelectcategory1") {
        return true;
    }

    //Handle error message here.
    alert("Please select a category");
    return false;
}
```

You can also validate your form once the form gets posted in PHP with:

```
if ($_POST['sendTo'] === 'pleaseSelectcategory1') {
    // Redirect back to form or do whatever
}
```

Comment: I add all these bits and the form still sends with the "Please select category" field is selected and lands in my mail. Im missing something :|

Comment: Check if your Javascript function is being called at all by putting `alert(document.getElementById("sendTo").value);` right above the if statement in `validateForm()` and see if 1. the function is being called, 2. the value from the selectbox is getting retrieved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In pure JavaScript you can use the following function:

```
function checkCategory(){
  if(document.getElementById('sendTo').value === 'pleaseSelectcategory1') {
    alert("You need to select category");
    //This is to ensure that the form doesn't get submitted.
    return false;
  }
}
```

Either use `onclick="javascript:checkCategory();"` on the button or the form itself `onsubmit="javascript:checkCategory();"`

In PHP you can just use:

```
if($_POST['sendTo'] == "pleaseSelectcategory1")
{ 
  //However you want to handle the the fact the user selected the option
}
```